# what does getNextEntry() do?

Tags: java, zip

I have checked java api document, it says `getNextEntry()` Reads the next ZIP file entry and positions the stream at the beginning of the entry data.

what does it mean "reads the NEXT zip file"? why the "NEXT" ?

I have this piece of code, what's the point of this line　`ze = zin.getNextEntry()`？

```
  public void unzip() { 
    try  { 
      FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(_zipFile); 
      ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(fin); 
      ZipEntry ze = null; 
      while ((ze = zin.getNextEntry()) != null) { 
        Log.v("Decompress", "Unzipping " + ze.getName()); 

        if(ze.isDirectory()) { 
          _dirChecker(ze.getName()); 
        } else { 
          FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(_location + ze.getName()); 
          for (int c = zin.read(); c != -1; c = zin.read()) { 
            fout.write(c); 
          } 

          zin.closeEntry(); 
          fout.close(); 
        } 

      } 
      zin.close(); 
    } catch(Exception e) { 
      Log.e("Decompress", "unzip", e); 
    } 

  }
```

Comment: can you check my updated question? why this example code put `ze = zin.getNextEntry()` in the beginning? so it start to unzip from the second file within the zip?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It reads the next *entry* within the zip file.

A zip file logically contains main other files - so `foo.zip` can contain files `a.txt` and `b.txt`. The `getNextEntry()` moves you on to the next file within the archive.

(I've never been particularly keen on the way that [`ZipInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.html) is modeled using inheritance from `InputStream`, but that's a different matter.)

Comment: so, if I start to unzip myfolder.zip which contains a.txt, b.txt, if I call ze = zin.getNextEntry(), it will move to b.txt and bypass a.txt? then whats the point to write `ze = zin.getNextEntry()` in the beginning? (I have updated my question, and posted the examle code there)

Comment: @Jolin: Yes. (Although you mean need to call `getNextEntry()` to move onto the first entry to start with - I can't remember offhand.)

Comment: (Re: The inheritance. I think it just makes the class diagrams that we had in the nineties look sexier.)